# Always open application from Splashscreen in Android

Tags: android

I have 4 Activities.**Splash Screen -> Login Screen -> Home Screen -> User Screen**. When I am in My Application's Home Screen I had pressed **Device HOME Button** at that time application going to background. If I open the application again it shows from Application's home screen. Now I need to show Splash then Login Screen for every time.I have called ***finish()*** for every ***Intent calls***. How to do this ?

Comment: call finish in onPause()

Comment: From Home screen I had used StartActivityforResult also.When that was called at that time also activity will be in onpause mode.

Comment: Thanks  Shayan pourvatan . I had handle this with OnRestart() state.

Answer (score 2):

In HomeScreen Activity, write this in onResume()-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Spalsh.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest file, in the Splash Screen activity (which I assume to be the root activity) add the following line

```
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
```

Comment: Is your Splash Screen activity the root activity?

Comment: Did you relaunch the app from long press home? If not please post your manifest.

Comment: Did you set any flag to your home activity or splash screen activity. If not then it is a bug, see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#clear

Answer (score 0):

Use this for the activity in your AndroidManifest.xml `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`